# Behavior of Spring Kafka Consumers Running in Kubernetes POD- Dropping messages

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a use-case where in need to persist Kafka messages into SQL Database and in no scenario I should lose messages. We have 9 partitions for the topic and using Spring boot/Kubernetes cloud deployment model.
I have configured `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with

```
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    
 factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAsyncAcks(true);
```

My KafkaListener class `implements AcknowledgingMessageListener, ConsumerSeekAware` interfaces.
Inside the method annotated with `@KafkaListener`, I am committing the offsets manually using `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` only after successful db inserts (the save method returns a flag 'Y' on success, by default the flag is initialized with 'N').
For any exceptions OR when the flag returned is 'N' I am doing `acknowledgment.nack(1000)` and it is the final step of processing. 
 

For testing I have created a Producer and posting 1000 messages of same format to the topic. Everything is working good. If I kill the consumers (Kubernetes PODs) one at a time such that at any point of time there is one running consumer(Kubernetes POD)  then I see all records I posted to the topic is saved into DB table. Remember once a  POD is killed it will come up automatically withing few secods/minutes.
But when I bring down/kill all the pods at the sametime such that no consumers are available at one point then I see some records which were posted to the topic but did not got saved into the DB table.

Where could have those records gone? Any suggestions to improve my code will be helpful.